# Product frontpage content - tab solution versus scrolling

Tags: scrolling, tabs

For a payment related project I want to create a product page.

**Example:** Paymill.com uses a combination of tabs and scrollable content on their front page.

**Question:** 
Is it better to have an only tab solution like [Asana](http://asana.com/product) or to have people scroll and read all the content like [6wunderkinder](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/about)

I feel some advantages of the tabs:

- users sees all categories at once and then can choose what info they want to see
- although, people do scroll below the "fold", they do not read, but skim and forget information
- scrolling psychologically feels like moving around and not being "on top" and "in control" of the information
- scrolling is an additional visual stimulus that needs cognitive processing (moving content)

On the other side, advantages of scrolling

- people are used to scrolling to find information
- therefore, users might even be more efficient in finding things
  -

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this question is slightly related more to marketing than User Experience. Each company has a different set of marketing goals that effects their decision on how to promote their product.

Personally, I prefer scrolling since it's easier to browse the information in the order the company wanted you to view it. Clicking on different types of tabs requires a little more effort in my opinion.

However, that doesn't mean you can't combine multiple solutions into one. Such as using anchor linked navigation that provides an alternative way to navigate through the content for a scroll based page.

Comment: OK. do you know any research that looked at this and actually measures how fast people find stuff, sign up, understand the content and like the website?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also have to consider the amount of information and the complexity of the content you have to display. In terms of scrolling, it is being able to structure content logically so that they know if and when it is good to scroll. Just keep in mind that tabs are good if you don't have too many categories, otherwise you might run into some usability issues as well. You might also want to consider how extensible the design concept is (e.g. you may want to add more categories in the future) for both tab and scrolling for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What is your audience - are most of your visitors from mobile platforms where scrolling is usual? What is your business - does your project for single product/service or for warehouse with thousand of positions? Etc... There are no universal report for the whole UI in the world. Make your question more specific about your task or otherwise you obtain only subjective opinions of particular persons.

In general, as for me :-) scrolling is good for simple products and mobiles, tabs are good for categorized contents and desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think an important thing todo before deciding on where to put tabs or how long your page will be, would be to do some information architecture.

You need to create a hierarchy and chunk your information. Focus on describing your product and highlighting its features. What can be told visually? Once you start developing your homepage's story, then the best layout and interactivity will begin to decide itself.